# Making a simple Space Invaders Clone--pygame.time.delay causes a crash

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, syntax

I just started working on a really simple version of space invaders using Python, and I coded out the player spaceship sprite, the enemy sprites, and the bullet sprites.

I had it so that the ship moves horizontally with the mouse cursor, and a bullet fires with each mouse click.  The bullets collide with the enemies, removing both sprites and increasing the score by 1.

After all the enemies are dead, it prints "You Win!" at the top.  Everything was working fine.

**I then decided I wanted to add in levels and make the invaders move downward by a set amount every few seconds.  I threw in some time.sleep commands (yes, I remembered to import time at the beginning of the code), but when I ran the code, it caused a crash.**
I was confused though, because the Python shell threw no errors.

I figured that sleeping one section of the code while trying to get others to run may have caused some global error I was unaware of, so I decided to use pygame's integrated time delay commands to create the pauses I wanted, but I got the same black screen system crashes with no errors in the shell.  I couldn't find any similar problems, so I figured I would ask on here for some help with my code.  Sorry for including so much code--

if I could select only the sections I thought were problematic, I would only include those, but I have no idea where the problem is.  I used graphics for the spaceship and the invader sprites, thats what "invadersprite.jpeg" and "player.png" are.

Thanks in advance!

```
import pygame
import random

#Defining Colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)

level = 1

#---Defining the Space Invaders
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Block, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("invadersprite.jpeg").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        #This makes the 'invaders' advance every so often.
        #The exact time should be 20 times 2^(-level), so that
        #the wait time can never be negative and so that it decreases
        #with each level up.
        waittime = (1000.00 * (20.00*(2.00**(-1.00 * level))))//1
        if level == 0:
            self.rect.y = self.rect.y
        else:
            pygame.time.wait(waittime)
            self.rect.y = self.rect.y - 40



#---Defining the player
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect.x = (pos[0] - 50)
        self.rect.y = 650

#---Defining the bullets
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 15])
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= 12

#function used later to increment the level by one
def Levelup():
    level+=1

#function used later to regenerate the invaders without running through
#the entire while loop
def BlockGenerator():
    for i in range(25):
        block = Block()
        block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
        block.rect.y = random.randrange(500)
        block_list.add(block)
        all_sprites_list.add(block)

#--Initializing the game
pygame.init()

pygame.mouse.set_visible(1)

#Setting the width and height of the screen [width, height]
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

pygame.display.set_caption("Spaceship")

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(25):
    block = Block()
    block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(500)
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

player = Player()
all_sprites_list.add(player)

#Loop until user clicks the close button
done = False

#Score
score = 0

#formatting, to make the entire spaceship visible
player.rect.y = 370

#Manages how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#-----Main Program Loop------
while not done:
    #---Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        #---Processing other user actions

        #This handles the "Game Over" instance    
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and level == 0:
            done = True

        #This handles all other instances
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullet = Bullet()
            bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x + 47
            bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y
            all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
            bullet_list.add(bullet)

    all_sprites_list.update()

    for bullet in bullet_list:
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)

        for block in block_hit_list:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            score += 1


        if bullet.rect.y < -10:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)


    #---Drawing the screen

    #Screen clear & fill        
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    #drawing the sprites
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    #Outputting the score and level onto the game
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 20, True, False)
    text = font.render("Score: %s" % (score), True, BLUE)
    screen.blit(text, [312, 30])
    text3 = font.render("Level %s" % (level), True, BLUE)
    screen.blit(text3, [450, 30])

    #Once the player kills all 25 invaders, this is executed
    if score == 25:
        font1 = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 40, True, False)
        text2 = font1.render("You Win!", True, GREEN)
        screen.blit(text2, [285, 150])

        #The "You Win!" message shows for roughly 5 seconds,
        #then the player advances to the next level.
        pygame.time.wait(5000)
        Levelup()

    #"Game Over" instance
    #Once a block advances to the same y coordinate as the player,
    #The game ends
    for block in block_list:
        if block.rect.y > 600:
            level = 0
            font2 = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 40, True, False)
            text4 = font.render["You Lose!", 40, True, RED]
            screen.blit(text4, [285, 150])
            #After this, the game loop runs through again, but this time
            #Level is set to 0, making the invaders stationary
            #The "You Lose" message should show
            #Once the player clicks, the game terminates


    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(40)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching this incorrectly, calling [`pygame.time.wait`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.wait) (and the same applies to `time.sleep`) stops everything, you can't even update the display, everything just stops while other processes get to use the CPU, and then it continues from where it stopped.

If you insist on using `pygame.time.wait` then call it from a thread that waits a certain amount of time and then updates everything at once, allowing the main thread to go about its business handling events and what not, this method also allows you to invoke `pygame.time.wait` with a short time period to *yield* the CPU to your other threads  so they have a chance to do their processing.

**Note:** python has a ***Global Interpreter Lock*** that makes it impossible for any two pieces of python code in the same process to run at the same time.  So when using threading, you have to be sure that you're yielding the ***Global Interpreter Lock*** often enough for other threads to get the chance to run.  This done simply by a call to `time.sleep` or `pygame.time.wait`.

Another alternative is to set up a clock and whenever 5 seconds has elapsed since a certain sprite has moved downwards, move it downwards and record the current time in field local to the sprite.  This way, you don't have to deal with the messy threading/yielding dynamic.